# Error while attempting to create a program to reverse a string

Tags: c#, string, reverse

Everything I have read on the internet makes me think this program should run but I keep getting an error. The error states:

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'system.collections.generic.IEnumerable' to 'string'. An implicit conversion exists".

Am I missing something?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string entry;

        Console.Write("Input String: ");
        entry = Console.ReadLine();

        entry = entry.Reverse();
        //Error occurs here ^             

        Console.Write(entry);

        Console.ReadKey(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The call to `entry.Reverse()` gives you a collection of characters.

You can use the constructor of string that accepts a character array, to store the value.

```
var myReversedString = new string(entry.Reverse().ToArray());
```

Or to just write it to the console:

```
Console.Write(entry.Reverse().ToArray());
```

---

The `WriteLine()` method has a lot of overloads, and can accept a lot of different parameter types, but a list is not one of them. So it uses the overload that accepts an `object`, then calls `ToString()` on it, which outputs the class name... so you see something like:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+<ReverseIterator>d__a0`1[System.Char]
```